# At which stage OpenGL goes left-handed?

Tags: opengl

I know that OpenGL operate in right-handed mode in user space (in fact it don't care about in which system we work) and only goes left-handed after every user stage is completed.
[learnopengl](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems) says (emphasize mine)

> Note that in normalized device coordinates OpenGL actually uses a left-handed system (**the projection matrix switches the handedness**).

However, I can't see how this statement could be true. With this simple example: let's say ModelViewProjection = Identity, the projection matrix does nothing so the final vertex is still right-handed.

If we test it, we can see that a an object rendered at a z = -0.5 will be hidden by another object at a z = -0.1, which should mean that that clip space is still right-handed, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normalized device space and clip space are left handed. The clipping rule is *-w <= x, y, z <= w*. That the model and view coordinate systems are usually right-handed is just common convection. But "OpenGL" is neither left- nor right-handed (except legacy OpenGL matrix functions produce right-handed matrices). Even OpenGL does not change the system.
The usual orthographic or perspective projection matrix generated with [`glm::ortho`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00245.html#ga71777a3b1d4fe1729cccf6eda05c8127) or [`glm::perspective`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00245.html#ga1bb3652e43f824d8c1dd5b9e60c80437) (or [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml), [`glFrustum`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glFrustum.xml)) inverts the z-axis. That is, it turns a right-handed system into a left-handed system and a left-handed system into a right-handed system. Using the identity matrix for the projection matrix does not invert the z-axis and does not change the system.
However, whether an object is occluded by another object depends on the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) and the depth function.

Comment: But since it invert the Z axis, why the scene isn't flipped in Z axis in the final image if we compare identity result / ortho results ?

Comment: @rafoo The z axis points into the view (x points right and y points up). The "depth" is "flipped".

Comment: I will reformulate my question. If `glm::ortho` invert the z-axis, then NOT using `glm::ortho` will not flip the z-axis. So how we come with an inverted z-axis in this case? And if the z axis points into the view (towards the user), that means it's a right handed system.

Comment: @rafoo *"I will reformulate my question. If glm::ortho invert the z-axis, then NOT using glm::ortho will not flip the z-axis. So how we come with an inverted z-axis in this case"* -As  a matter of fact, in this case it is not inverted. I don't know how you come to the conclusion that it is, but that's just plain wrong

Comment: But in both cases, in world space, an object at Z will be covered by another at Z' > Z. If in one case z is flipped and not the other, shouldn't the entire scene be flipped in Z, which is not the case?

Comment: @rafoo No, you are wrong. Is the depth test enabled? Enable the depth test, make all matrices the identity matrix and draw 2 rectangles. One with z=0.5 and one with z=-0.5. That with z=-0.5 covers that with z=0.5.

Comment: I actually don't have tested with an identity matrix, I thought it was the same. I will try it. So, with an identity, matrix, an object at world space Z will be covered by another object at Z' *<* Z ?

Comment: @rafoo For `Z' < Z`, `Z'` covers `Z` if the depth test is enabled and the depth function is `GL_LESS`

Comment: @rafoo: The thing you may be misunderstanding is this: the coordinate system is defined by how the data gets *used*. Clip space and NDC space (using default depth ranges) is left-handed. If you try to pass data that you built expecting a right-handed interpretation, with no matrix that flips handedness, then you will not get the results you expect. Triangle facing will be backwards, near becomes far, etc.

Comment: Juste a final question, in view space (with `glm::lookAt`), it is left or right handed? Because zNear < zFar, it looks like it is left handed though it is run before the handness flipping by the projection matrix.